# i need to scroll down to the end of the ListView using onData() in espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am using espresso onData() to scroll down to the end of the ListView but it is not scrooling.

```
onData(is(instanceOf(List.class))).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.navigationList)).atPosition(17);
```

and

```
onData(is(instanceOf(ListView.class))).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.navigationList)).atPosition(17);
```

both of these are not scrolling to the end of the listview. Can someone help me out with this ?

below is ListView in xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigationList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/ivider"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />
```

Comment: What is the action you trying to perform or validate? Also have you tried using `anything()`  `onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.navigationList)).atPosition(17);`

Comment: just tried with anything() and it worked. Thank you vk.4884.

Comment: Glad it worked. No problem :)